# Creation of a Linux Virtual Machine from command line

Tags: linux, cloud, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Is it possible to launch a script that would:

- create one Virtual Machine
- install Linux distribution(Lubuntu iso file) on it (with some required configuration:  french keyboard, english languages, password etc)
- and finally proceed some configuration inside the running VM  (add guest Additions, install some programs, configure one specified static ip adress, etc...) ?

I am able to proceed all this steps graphically but it is really time consuming and i need to proceed all theses steps several times.

PS: i am aware of the clone option in VirtualBox but

1. it suppose that i already have one VM with the specified options on my host. Since my goal is to launch a cloud on several machines, many of theses machine don't even one VM.
2. When i make a clone i still have some configurations to proceed (change the static ip, chanhe the host name, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create virtual machines from the CLI, I suggest you to use [virsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh), however you will need to install the following groups: Virtualization Client, Virtualization Hypervisor, Virtualization Platform, Virtualization Tools, also you need to start the libvirtd daemon.

Regarding your question about changing some configurations to multiple VMs you can use [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).